# How to trigger an element within the same container using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a site that dynamically produces the code below. It has multiple instances of div.container and its children. The problem is that when I click on the thumbnails(.color-thumbs img), it also triggers the change on all images(.imgWrapper img). What I need to do is create a unique trigger for the thumbnails which will only affect the image within the same container.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.color-thumbs img').click(function() {
  var thmb = this;
  var src = this.src;
  $('.color-thumbs img').parent('.imgWrapper').append('crayz');

  $('.imgWrapper img').fadeOut(400,function(){
      thmb.src = this.src;
      $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
  });
});
```

```css
.color-thumbs img{
  margin-right:3px;
  margin-top:3px;
  width:30px;
  height: 30px;
  float:left;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/cf5" />
  </div>

  <div class="color-thumbs">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/444" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/cf5" />
  </div>

  <div class="color-thumbs">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/444" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />
  </div>
</div>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) to fine the `container` element to which the clicked `img` belongs to then use .find() to find the target `.imgWrapper img` element inside it like

```js
$('.color-thumbs img').click(function() {
  var thmb = this;
  var src = this.src;

  $(this).closest('.container').find('.imgWrapper img').stop().fadeOut(400, function() {
    $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
  });
});
```

```css
.color-thumbs img {
  margin-right: 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 4em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/cf5" />
  </div>

  <div class="color-thumbs">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/444" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/cf5" />
  </div>

  <div class="color-thumbs">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/444" />
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x160/f1f" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.color-thumbs img').click(function() {
  var thmb = this;
  var src = this.src;
  $(thmb).parent('.imgWrapper').append('crayz');

  $(thmb).closest('.imgWrapper img').fadeOut(400,function(){
      thmb.src = this.src;
      $(this).fadeIn(400)[0].src = src;
  });
});
```